# Homelab networking adding a new router and VLAN for segregation

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vlan, cisco-router

I hope you and your loved ones are safe and healthy.

I am a self-funded student in last year of college. I need to create network for my final year research.

I am want to integrate a Cisco Integrated Service Router "RV-345" into my network & use VLAN to segregate traffic.

**Current setup:**
Netgear Wi-Fi router is the only component carrying out network access and routing. Here is a simple representation of the network:

[image: current_state]

1. WAN port is connected via CAT-6 cable to ISPs box.
2. NAS with 2 network port working in bond mode (combined speed instead of fault tolerance) connected to port 1 & 2 of the Netgear.
3. Workstation with 2 Intel NICs connected to ports 3 & 4 of the Netgear router. This workstation has ESXi installed and 12 VMs running on it.

**Proposed setup:**
Cisco ISR 345 will carry out wired access and routing while setting Netgear to access point mode. Further requirements for VLANs:

[image]

1. VMs running on ESXi require separation using VLANs. I will have multiple VLANs which while segregated from each other need access for few central services like the DHCP, DNS (reachable via Wi-Fi access point port) and one VLAN on the ESXi which will be for logging.
2. Currently, a Raspberry Pi running DHCP and DNS servers provides these network services. This is connected via Wi-Fi for now. This is important to note as I would need Wi-Fi to extend all VLANs to reach these central services.
3. Raspberry Pis will eventually be connected via ethernet, but right now, they are connected via Wi-Fi.

**Questions:**

1. As per my understanding, ESXi is where I have to create the VLANs and extend them via Cisco ISR. Is this correct?
2. How do I ensure that the Wi-Fi port forwards all VLANs? In other words, how do I ensure that backbone network services (DHCP, DNS) are available irrespective of the VLANs
3. From the NAS, I have a volume mounted on the workstation using iSCSI. Are there any implications using VLANs on this?

**Follow up questions**
I have few follow-up questions to help me settle this without disruption:

1. Currently I am using a Raspberry Pi to host DNS/DHCP servers. This is running without a VLAN and is provisioning IPs from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.0.254.

**Questions:**

**A.** I will need the DHCP scope from current to 192.168.0.0. to 192.168.255.254 right? (My VLAN ID equals the IP pool in the third octet. Hence VLAN100 where shared services are located I will have 192.168.100.0-254).

**B.** The port where Raspberry Pi will be physically connected port 5: This port will have following setting:

B.1 - Tagged for VLANs 10 through 100

B.2 - Untagged for VLAN 1

**2. Port VLAN settings:**

I am confused in this setting. What should be the setting for ports running multiple:

**A.** Ports housing multiple VLANs such as the virtulisation (ESXi) will run VLANs 30 through 50. What should the port setting be?

A.1 Tagged for 30-50

A.2 Untagged for all other?

**B.** What about ports needing ALL VLANs such as the Wi-Fi?

B.1 Tagged for ALL VLANs except - VLAN 1 on which only the Router's management interface is? I don't mind taking router access through wired medium only.

Thanking you in anticipation.

I apologise if the post is missing information and more is required. Kindly let me know if something needs to be added.

Answer (score 0):

> As per my understanding, ESXi is where I have to create the VLANs and extend them via Cisco ISR. Is this correct?

You're probably correct that you have to create VLAN *interfaces* on ESXi (I have not used VLANs on ESXi, or in fact used ESXi at all, but that's how VLANs work on most other hosts).

However, VLANs themselves aren't really created at any specific location, they just exist by agreement. As long as the ESXi and the gateway and switches in-between agree to tag/untag specific VLAN IDs that's all there is to "creating" a VLAN.

> How do I ensure that the Wi-Fi port forwards all VLANs? In other words, how do I ensure that backbone network services (DHCP, DNS) are available irrespective of the VLANs
> [...]
> Currently, a Raspberry Pi running DHCP and DNS servers provides these network services. This is connected via Wi-Fi for now. This is important to note as I would need Wi-Fi to extend all VLANs to reach these central services.

This question is actually *two* questions with two different answers.

Regarding attaching the Raspberry Pi to all VLANs:

- Although Wi-Fi can technically carry VLAN tags like any other ethertype, I'm not sure whether your hardware and drivers will handle them correctly; e.g. there might be MTU issues. I would recommend having an Ethernet connection available.

  The issue is that regular Wi-Fi APs are *not* designed to directly carry VLAN-tagged traffic – they're designed around a different approach, where each VLAN is bridged to a different SSID. (For example, an AP could be connected to a "management" VLAN, a "guest Wi-Fi" VLAN, and "employees Wi-Fi" VLAN, the latter being two separate SSIDs.)

  So while this question is answerable for *some* Wi-Fi access points, I would honestly not spend too much time with trying a regular consumer Netgear do it. It might be easy but it might be literally impossible.

Regarding making *services* such as DNS and DHCP available to all VLANs:

- DNS in particular **does not have to be on the same VLAN.** It's just a standard IP-based service that can perfectly well go through routers. So you only need the DNS server to be in *one* VLAN, with one IP address, and all your subnets can reach it through the routers/gateways that you have.
- DHCP does need to be available in the VLAN directly, but it can be *relayed.* Your router could act as a DHCP relay agent (also known as "DHCP helper"), where it receives the broadcast 'discover' & 'request' packets and relays them via unicast to the real server (and relays the responses back).

  Because the relayed DHCP packets are unicast to a specific IP address, this again allows the real DHCP server to be literally anywhere in the network; it no longer needs to have direct access to the actual VLANs.
- IPv6 RA is yet different. It *has* to be broadcast by the router itself, not by any other device, so you couldn't have moved it to a RPi in the first place. Fortunately, IPv6 RA is also a fully stateless system, so there's no reason to move it anyway.

> From the NAS, I have a volume mounted on the workstation using iSCSI. Are there any implications using VLANs on this?

Unlikely.

> A. I will need the DHCP scope from current to 192.168.0.0. to 192.168.255.254 right? (My VLAN ID equals the IP pool in the third octet. Hence VLAN100 where shared services are located I will have 192.168.100.0-254).

Each VLAN is a separate layer-2 network and needs to have its own DHCP "scope" – they don't only differ in the address pool, but also in the options to advertise (e.g. the "Default Gateway" option obviously has to be different).

> What should be the setting for ports running multiple:

The answer is the same for all cases, whether it's the ESXi or the Raspberry Pi or the Netgear access point or the Cisco router. Your Wi-Fi *doesn't* need "ALL VLANs", it still needs specific VLANs that it intends to serve, same as ESXi etc.

In all cases, at most *one* VLAN can be left untagged (aka native) – all others have to be tagged, because the tags are the only way for both ends to distinguish which VLAN to put the packets in.

Usually the "management" VLAN is the one that remains untagged. (So in your case both the RPi and the Netgear will probably want VLAN 10 untagged? I can't fully make sense of your VLAN descriptions.)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I've edited the original question with few follow-up questions. Could I kindly get assistance with that?